# How to config the default root index in hosting server

Tags: indexing, filezilla

I wanted to put the index.php file of my website in a public file on my server, but consequently, when I tap the url, it is not directing me to the index, but to the folder which contains all of the folder of my website.

I try to put a .htaccess file in the root of the folder containing my website. It worked with my local virtual host wampserver, but not with the real host (where I put files with filezila). I show you the line code I wrote in .htaccess, which worked with wampserver, but not with the actual used server for internet ::

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [QSA,L]

I try also to put the absolute path but same thing. Does someone have an idea about what I have to do to config the index path of my server ? (for a subdomain) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to remove the first line:

Options +FollowSymlinks

My server already had it activated and didn't support the instruction twice.